# If switch/case capable comparing multiple values?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

here is what I have now,

```js
switch (true) {
  case moveOneType === "rock" || moveOneType === "paper" || moveOneType === "scissors":
  case moveTwoType === "rock" || moveTwoType === "paper" || moveTwoType === "scissors":
  case moveThreeType === "rock" || moveThreeType === "paper" || moveThreeType === "scissors":
    break;
```

does switch accept multiple expression or can I use `||` and `&&` in case value?

If not, I'll just use `if/else` instead

Comment: What you currently have will run fine. Does it not work the way you'd expect?

Comment: It has to be an expression so you can have any number of conditions. Why dont you test it and see? You should also read up on `break`

Comment: @Blender https://github.com/MaDonghui/project-1-rock-paper-scissors-x99/blob/master/js/game-logic.js here is what I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to do but I will try and explain your code. Here is your code:

```
switch (true) {
  case moveOneType === "rock" || moveOneType === "paper" || moveOneType === "scissors":
  case moveTwoType === "rock" || moveTwoType === "paper" || moveTwoType === "scissors":
  case moveThreeType === "rock" || moveThreeType === "paper" || moveThreeType === "scissors":
    break;
```

**Explanation**

All that will happen is the expression will be evaluated, in this case the expression is the `true` within the `switch` and since `true` is `true`, execution will go into the block if any of the cases provided matches a `true`. Otherwise execution will not go into the block.

Here is a test. Please note I have added the number 1 to the end of the variable values so none of the cases check to true:

```
var moveOneType = "rock1";
var moveTwoType = "paper1"; 
var moveThreeType = "scissors1";

switch(true)
{
    case moveOneType === "rock" || moveOneType === "paper" || moveOneType === "scissors":
        alert('case 1');
    case moveTwoType === "rock" || moveTwoType === "paper" || moveTwoType === "scissors":
        alert('case 2');
    case moveThreeType === "rock" || moveThreeType === "paper" || moveThreeType === "scissors":
        alert('case 3');
        break;
}
```

[<== Fiddle Me ==>](https://jsfiddle.net/1vbarL86/6/)

Now that it is clear how execution goes into the block, here is another test which will clarify why your code is full of surprises. In the code below we are switching on the value of `hello` and since it equals `some garbage`, execution will go inside the block. Why? Because `case 'some garbage'` evaluates to true. So guess what: Since you have no `break` between the cases, every case will be evaluated and you will see 4 alerts.

```
var moveOneType = "rock";
var moveTwoType = "paper"; 
var moveThreeType = "scissors";

var hello = 'some garbage';

switch(hello)
{
    case 'some garbage': alert('garbage');
    case moveOneType === "rock" || moveOneType === "paper" || moveOneType === "scissors":
        alert('case 1');
    case moveTwoType === "rock" || moveTwoType === "paper" || moveTwoType === "scissors":
        alert('case 2');
    case moveThreeType === "rock" || moveThreeType === "paper" || moveThreeType === "scissors":
        alert('case 3');
    break;
}
```

[<== Fiddle Me ==>](https://jsfiddle.net/u47vxaaa/)

If you do not want all the cases to be evaluated then add a break after the case.

> does switch accept multiple expression

Sure it does as shown below. The expression `moveOneType === "rock" && moveTwoType === "paper"` will be evaluated and the value will be `true` and if at least one case is also `true` then execution will go inside the block:

```
var moveOneType = "rock";
var moveTwoType = "paper"; 
var moveThreeType = "scissors";

switch(moveOneType === "rock" && moveTwoType === "paper")
{
    case moveOneType === "rock" || moveOneType === "paper" || moveOneType === "scissors":
        alert('case 1');
    case moveTwoType === "rock" || moveTwoType === "paper" || moveTwoType === "scissors":
        alert('case 2');
    case moveThreeType === "rock" || moveThreeType === "paper" || moveThreeType === "scissors":
        alert('case 3');
        break;
}
```

[<== Fiddle Me ==>](https://jsfiddle.net/1663dtvf/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the awesome answer! I have re-wrote everything in a normal way xD but it is good to know that switch can do this!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine, although it is probably not the most common use of `switch`.

The reason why it works is that the expression in the `case` statement is evaluated and the result is used, so a `case` statement with an expression evaluating to `true` would match in `switch(true)`.

Here is a simple example

```
function getValue() {
  console.log('get value');
  return 2;
}


switch (true) {
case getValue() === 1 || getValue() === 2:
  console.log('ok');
  break;
case false:
  console.log('not ok');
  break;
default:
  break;
}
```

You can see that it outputs `get value` twice, one for the first `getValue()` and one for the second (i.e. after the `||`). The result evaluates to `true`, as `getValue() === 2` returns 2. As we are using `switch(true)`, as long as the expression in the case statement returns `true`, the `case` statement will be executed, so in this example, `ok` will be outputted.

Now, I am not exactly sure what your `switch` statement is supposed to do in the first place, so I cannot tell you if this is a good way to handle your issue or not, but it is by no mean incorrect to use an expression returning a boolean and match it with `true`.

Comment: I just trying to check if the input for is rock scissor or paper, I know this can be easily done in `if/else` but I wanna try `switch`

Comment: here is the repo on GitHub, mocha test included

Comment: *"The reason why it works is that when you have an expression in the case statement, it is evaluated and the result is used"* This sounds like you may not always have an expression following `case`. But it is always an expression.

Comment: @FelixKling Indeed, thank you for pointing this out. I updated my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `if/else` instead.
Your `switch` statement can be an expression. But the case conditions are the value you are the possible value you are expecting from the output of your `switch` statement. Here is the [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

```
    var moveOneType;

    if(moveOneType === "rock" || moveOneType === "paper" || moveOneType === "scissors"){}
    else if(moveTwoType === "rock" || moveTwoType === "paper" || moveTwoType === "scissors"){}
    else if(moveThreeType === "rock" || moveThreeType === "paper" || moveThreeType === "scissors"){}
```

Comment: Thank you, since this is about logic I think I'll just simply use `if/else` Just trying new things

Comment: Definitely, when you want to do logic, `if/else` are the best. `switch` is useful only you when to check the different value of a certain variable

Comment: Why is the condition wrong? I believe it is correct, although it is not the most common use of `switch`.

Comment: I mean for what he is trying to do, the condition is wrong. Basically, `true` will be considered as a variable in his case. And this is not what he is trying to achieve. Actually, I can't even tell in which condition his `case` will be fired up. Because you can't even declare a variable of name `true`.

Comment: Oh right, I used `undefined` before, but that is string not boolean, I think I can achieve what I want by using  switch nest but come on, the point I want to use `switch` is for the clean look

Comment: @edkeveked I think the switch he wrote and your `if`/`else` are basically doing the same thing, as long as he adds a `break` at the end of each `case` statement.